# What does 'Notice added' mean in the edit history of a question?

Tags: discussion, edits, post-notice

While going through the edit history of a question, I came across the following messages in the history:

> **Notice added** Reward existing answer by USER

> **Notice removed** Reward existing answer by USER

Screenshot of the same:
[image]

What does 'Notice' mean? Does 'Reward' refer to a bounty?

Comment: It's a bounty. The notice is the bounty reason chosen.

Comment: Oh, so does that mean the bounty reason was chosen and later removed?

Comment: The bounty ended and [the notice that was on top of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7f76.png) was removed.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks! One more thing, I've seen bounty reasons stating that they want to draw more attention to a post. What is meant by 'reward an existing answer'? Does it mean that the bounty would be awarded to anyone who answered?

Comment: The bounties are always either handed manually or, if they expire, automatically based on votes. The reason for the bounty is just what the user who posted the bounty chose from a list of available ones. There is no mechanism in place to detect if they abide by that reason. If they chose "reward an existing answers" most likely they want to hand it manually to somebody who already posted. Automatic bounty award only takes into account answers posted after the bounty started. See the FAQ for more details: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

Answer (score 6):

Any post with a blue box (aside from the closure notice) has a corresponding 'Notice added' event in their timeline. This happens when a bounty is offered, or when a [moderator locks a post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40480/revisions). When the bounty ends, there no longer needs to be a notice, so it is automatically removed in a 'notice removed' event. Moderators can also [add certain notices](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/287772/timeline) directly.

Comment: One place we use notices (without locking) here on MSO is with burninations especially large ones. We have a series of notices to indicate what phase of the process we are in. See for example [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/296710/revisions)

Comment: Also a complete list of posts with any kind of notice can be found on any site at [/annotated-posts](/annotated-posts) (no reputation required)